# How to use SQL previous records calculated value in current record?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use previous records calculated value to perform current record calculations.

In the below image, we have written a small query which calculates the closing stock of all days. The calculated closing stock value of day 1 should be used as Actual stock for day 2 and similarly the calculated closing stock value of day 2 should be used as Actual stock for day 3 and so on till the end of the dates. We would like to perform this logic in a single select query. We tried to use SQL LAG(), BOUNDED Preceding but nothing turned to be positive.

[image]

Comment: you may get some use out of the LAG function

Comment: Thanks Paul for the reply. We tried to use SQL LAG function but I could not use it for the calculated columns. Could you pls. update & share me the query?

Comment: Look into recursive CTEs

Comment: Put this in a CTE and then use LAG

Comment: Perhaps you could post your attempt to use the LAG function and that would give folks something to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PART_NUMBER, DATE) AS Rownum,
    PART_NUMBER, DATE, ACTUALSTOCK, GROSS, BACKLOG, RECEIPT,
    SUM(ACTUALSTOCK - (GROSS + BACKLOG) + RECEIPT) OVER (ORDER BY PART_NUMBER, DATE) AS CLOSINGSTOCK
FROM Tbl_PV_Parts_Dtl_MGMT_cur
WHERE PART_NUMBER = '0112107261' AND
      DATE BETWEEN '20151021' AND '20151031')
SELECT
    PART_NUMBER, DATE,
    CASE WHEN Rownum = 1 THEN ACTUALSTOCK ELSE LAG(CLOSINGSTOCK) OVER(ORDER BY Rownum) END,
    GROSS, BACKLOG, RECEIPT,
    CLOSINGSTOCK
FROM CTE
```